# Form won't POST without Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

We (the entire team) have been pulling hair over this problem for the last 2 days. For some strange reason our Zend Framework 1.11.2 will not let us post plain form into the controller unless we create a Zend_Form class.

HTML in view file (no javascript, nothing):

```
<html><body>
 <form action="/index/login/" method="post">            
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
    <p><input type=submit name="ac" class="btn btn-success" value="Login"></p>
  </form></body></html>
```

Index Controller:

```
public function loginAction() 
{   
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getParam('email')) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($request);
    }
}
```

$request->getParams() is empty!

But if we create a Zend_Form or pass the fields in as GET then $request->getParams() is filled with data.

I just don't get it. Is there something in Zend that you have to turn off to use plain form? We think we've tried everything, accessing global $_POST and $_REQUEST variables, and calling $request->getPost(). All empty unless we create a Zend_Form class and instantiate it inside the controller.

Comment: That's strange. It shouldn't be a problem. Have you tried setting up a plain ZF app to see if you can do a post? Otherwise I'd check if you have any Zend_Controller_Plugins doing an processing in the predispatch hook.

Comment: It's funny the amount of problems we can solve when using an interactive debugger. Looking at the nature of your issue, I'm quite sure that neither you nor your team has the habit to use debuggers. Am I right? =P I meant, not Zend_Debug::dump(), but Xdebug or Zend Debugger...

Comment: We step through the debugger. We are using Xdebug and Eclipse PDT. Nothing - Nada. Empty $_POST. The debug dump is just in case we stepped over something. :(

Plain fresh ZF app works just fine. We just want to get to the bottom of it in case it is something we missed with Zend_Form.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? Could be you're caught up in all the changes made to PHP and ZF due to bug fixes in recent versions of both. Especially if you have a patched PHP and an older version of ZF. Something to consider.

Comment: ZF has no way of knowing the different between a plain HTML form and a `Zend_Form`, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  If you use a tool like [livehttpheaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) do you see anything strange with the request?

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="ac" class="btn btn-success" value="Login">` note the `"`'s around 'submit'.

Comment: @RockyFord, thank you so much for the versions pointer. We are running PHP 5.3.2 with Suhosin-Patch. The problem went away on our 5.4 sandboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an problem with your Form Action. Please use "baseUrl" View Helper or URL View Helper to create correct action url:

```
<?php
// correct action url

$actionURL = $this->url(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'login',
    'module'     => 'default',
));

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $actionURL; ?>" method="post">            
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
            <p><input type=submit name="ac" class="btn btn-success" value="Login"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: The view helper helps you organize/format your URL. The $actionURL will give you /index/login - same as before. I did give your suggestion a try just in case it was doing something more than a fancy URL. Still no luck.

Comment: hum url helper altough adds the full "url" /index/login results only in in http://localhost/index/login

Answer (score 0):

> ...pass the fields in as GET then $request->getParams() is filled with data.

Since you are crafting a form post, you will need to use the `getPost()` method.

```
public function loginAction() 
{   
    if ($email = $this->_request->getPost('email')) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that. $request->getPost().

Comment: `getRequest()` will access both GET and POST parameters, but I prefer using `getPost` as this prevents the user from easily injecting certain parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

First use the latest version

Zend Framework 1.11.11

Then try this code inside loginAction

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
{
print_r($this->_getAllParams());
}
```